# Why installing node.js via homebrew is (more) buggy?

Tags: macos, node.js, homebrew

When [installing](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) `node.js`, it's kind of *unexpected* to see:

> **Warning**: brew installs are known to be buggy

Why `brew` is more buggy (say, comparing with `port`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew formulas are, for the most part, community maintained. That means they are constantly being changed or updated and liable to have errors. Node.js probably ran into some of these errors, but they were likely fixed quickly. MacPorts has a more formal process of inclusion but the main con is that it's not nearly as updated.